# Hibernate, oauth2 could not obtain transaction-synchronized

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oauth-2.0

I tried to make my own customDetailsService and when I tried to call server for token using http:

POST http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123

I got exception as a result:

```
<UnauthorizedException xmlns="">
    <error>unauthorized</error>
    <error_description>Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread</error_description>
</UnauthorizedException>
```

What is more, when I debugged this I had determined that there is the problem with method userDaoImpl.findByLogin(login). But when I called it from my restController for test it worked and annotations were analogous.

@EnableTransactiomManagement is added in hibernate configuration and needed classes are annotated with @Transaction.

MyUserDetailsService

```
package com.maxim.spring.restcontroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDao;
import com.maxim.spring.model.User;

@Transactional
@Service("MyUserDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDaoImpl")
    private UserDao userDaoImpl;



    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        User user = userDaoImpl.findByLogin(login);


        if(user == null) {
            System.out.println("User was not found ");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(login);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tu powinienem byc i jestem");
            new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(), user.getPass(), getUserRole(user));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getUserRole(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRole()));

        return authorities;
    }
```

UserDaoImpl:

```
package com.maxim.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.maxim.spring.model.User;


@Transactional
@Repository("userDaoImpl")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements UserDao{

    public User findById(Integer id) {



    @Override
    public User findByLogin(String login) {
        System.out.println("w srodku1");
        Query qr = (Query) getSession().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.login=:login").setParameter("login", login);
        System.out.println("w srodku2");
        User u = (User) qr.list().get(0);
        System.out.println("w srodku3");
        return u;
    }





}
```

The hibernate configuration:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.maxim.spring.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.maxim.spring.model", "com.maxim.spring.services" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

**How to make it work? What are my mistakes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using getSession().getCurrentSession().......
if you put **getSession().openSession()**.....It will works.

more info [enter this discussion](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/websystique/secure_spring_rest_api_using_oauth2/oldest/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Transactional` method loadUserByUsername() call `@Transactional` method findByLogin() that is conflict, can't open 2 transactions.

Idea for you:

Remove all @Transactional above class and add @Transactional on methods that you want to be transactional. Your method loadUserByUsername() must be transactional but your method findByLogin() can't be transactional because it is called from transactional method.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the clue. I removed @Transactional from method loadUserByUsername() and afterwards from method findByLogin() instead but there is still the same fault.

Comment: You need to remove '@Transactional' above class, '@Transactional' annotation should be above method. 
The idea for you:

Comment: Does not work too.. probably this is oauth sercurity case.